# SQL Server 2008 - Set a value when the column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a SELECT statement on a SQL Server 2008 database.

```
SELECT Name, DOB, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip
FROM Users
```

However, if any of the above columns happen to be empty for a specific row, I want to put the value `NA` in the column.

Normally this would return:

```
SMITH^JOHN, 1/1/1980, 5140 N 1ST ST, NULL, NOWHERE, WA, 98221
DOE^JANE, 5/5/1970, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

What I want to be returned is:

```
SMITH^JOHN, 1/1/1980, 5140 N 1ST ST, NA, NOWHERE, WA, 98221
DOE^JANE, 5/5/1970, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
```

However, I don't want to actually update the database. I just want the `SELECT` statement to return this static value whenever the result is `NULL`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to use the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function.

```
SELECT
    Name
,   DOB
,   COALESCE(Address1, 'NA')
,   COALESCE(Address2, 'NA')
,   COALESCE(City, 'NA')
,   COALESCE(State, 'NA')
,   COALESCE(Zip, 'NA')
FROM Users
```

Answer (score 6):

In sql server 2008 there are two functions to replace **NULL** values with another values

**1. ISNULL** function required two parameters: the value to check and the replacement for null values

**ISNULL(value,replacement)**

**2.COALESCE**  function works a bit different **COALESCE** will take any number of parameters and return the first non-NULL value , I prefer COALESCE over ISNULL 'cause meets ANSI standarts, while ISNULL does not.

**COALESCE(value1,value1,value3, valueN,replacement)**

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
ISNULL(expression, value_if_expression_is_null)
```

As others have pointed out, COALESCE is also an option:

```
COALESCE(expression, expression2, expression3)
```

which returns the first non-null value

There is a detailed article describing the differences here:

http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  Name, DOB,
  (CASE WHEN Address1 IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE Address1 END) AS Address1,
  (CASE WHEN Address2 IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE Address2 END) AS Address2,
  ...
FROM Users
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  Name, DOB, Address1, 
  coalesce(Address2,'NA'), coalesce(City,'NA'), 
  coalesce(State,'NA'), coalesce(Zip,'NA')
FROM Users
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isnull`:

```
SELECT
    Name, 
    DOB, 
    isnull(Address1, 'NA') as [Address1], 
    isnull(Address2, 'NA') as [Address2], 
    isnull(City, 'NA') as [City], 
    isnull(State, 'NA') as [State], 
    isnull(Zip, 'NA') as [Zip]
FROM Users
```

You can also use `coalesce`, which is exactly like `isnull` except that it can take more than two arguments. The arguments are checked from left to right and the first non-null value is returned. Values must be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

**Handling NULL In SQL Server**

What Is NULL ?

- NULL means no result or unknown.
- NULL is not equal to NULL itself.
- A value of NULL is different from an empty or zero value.
- NULL is the smallest value in the sorting order.
- NULL are considered to be equal when the group by is executed.
- If a column in the  Group By clause contains rows with NULL, then these will be grouped into one group.

[Handling Null In SQL Server With Examples](http://www.sqlfeathers.com/2018/06/handling-null-in-sql-server.html)