# When statment to replace Null data

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
money
20.00
17.87
5.00
NULL
3.00
```

I want the null entries turned into zeroes. The money column is for money spent. Ive tried the following and it didnt like changing NUll to a dollar value.

```
select case money when 'NULL'  then  0  end
from mytable
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 - Set a value when the column is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231250/sql-server-2008-set-a-value-when-the-column-is-null)

Answer (score 3):

```
select coalesce(money, 0) from mytable
```

Coalesce will take the first non-null value in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT IsNull(money, 0)
FROM mytable
```

---

**EDIT**
If you want to *replace* the values in the table:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET money = 0
WHERE money Is Null
```

Comment: to have them replaced in MyTable?

Comment: @user2448666: To replace the values, you'll need an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the other two answers, I wasnted to explain why what you did was not right.

```
select case money when 'NULL'  then  0  end
from mytable
```

Here you are treating NULL as a string value. But NULL is a **condition** not a value. It means there is no known value. If you inserted the actual word 'null' into  the table in that field, then your code would have worked.

When you want to test for a NULL condition you use:

```
WHERE field1 IS NULL
```

or you change the value using coalesce or ISNULL. If you need to test for NULL as part of a case statement, then you would do it like this:

```
CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE T1 END
```

For simple cases like yours, COALESCE or ISNULL is best. But at times you may need to do a very complicated CASE and then it is handy to know how to do it.